# Can I splice a USB serial (with chip) directly onto a VGA male adapter to make a USB-to-DB9 serial cable?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, usb

I have quite a few older USB-to-whatever serial cables, and I found myself needing one that goes to DB9 for an old router... Is there any reason not to wire it to a VGA male adapter, which would (probably) fit? Haven't looked at the pinout yet online, since it will probably take me half an hour to find the damned cable in my hoard. If it is possible, please provide links. The chips in my spare serial cables vary widely in dmesg, but are all fully functional. Shoot me down ;)

---

The quick way is of course just to strip the serial cable, solder Tx to Rx, Rx to Tx, and ground to ground. No bells needed. For maximum convenience, the serial cable will stay attached in this way forever.

Comment: VGA does not use DB9. Shot down, as requested.

Comment: Thanks :) what miscellaneous hardware can I scavenge a DB9 connector from?

Comment: Any hardware that has a DB9 connector, presumably.

Comment: It'll take you half an hour to find the wire, and you're thinking of spending the same amount of time or longer (plus waiting for answers to this question) to **make** a cable to do the same thing?

Comment: Many older PCs & modems used RS-232 ports which have DB9 connectors.

Comment: Not rational or with crucial details worked out. Recommend close.

Comment: Is the router rs232 or ttl serial? You'd want to check before you fry the cable or the router

Comment: @Passerby: Well - it's certainly not fried, I just got junk output. Tried 40-50 different combinations of software||hardware flow control on||off, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, baud rates from 9600 and up. Then I bought a usb-to-db9 for 10$. Thanks though.

Comment: The thing is that usb to db9 twnd to support -12V to 12V rs232. Usb to ttl serial is 3.3V or 5V to 0V, which won't work with rs232 signals. That's why it was garbage output.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the protocols on wikipedia. The cable I used is TTL, but the driver that attached to it is listed as a USB-RS232 bridge device. All my spare cables seem to be TTL, so I'll wait for the one I ordered earlier today.

Comment: The MAX232 chip is pretty neat for this... http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX220-MAX249.pdf - less than 2€. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

Won't fit. VGA has the same shell size, but 15 pins instead of 9.

Edit: also, even if you have a USB UART cable with, say, an FTDI USB UART chip, the voltage levels out of that chip won't be correct for RS-232 serial and there is a good possibility that your USB UART chip will be damaged. If you want to convert a TTL level UART into an RS-232 cable, you will also need an RS-232 level shifter chip such as the MAX232.

Answer (score 1):

re:  "Is there any reason not to wire it to a VGA male adapter, which would (probably) fit?"

Yes there is a reason that it won't work--a VGA port uses a DB15 connector--not a DB9 connector & they aren't plug compatible.

You're going to need a USB to RS-232 converter because the protocols of your USB port & your router aren't directly pin-2-pin compatible.

Comment: Curses... The cable I was just about to cut open is a serial cable for an arduino nano. Doesn't it use the right protocol? Edit: I don't need hardware flow control.

Comment: USB uses a multilayered protocol.  RS232 has a very slow data transfer rate so syncing would most likely need to be buffered.  I think you're going to need a USB-RS232 converter to manage that & other signaling for you.

Comment: Right, but the chip in the cable handles serial, and is registered in my dmesg as a serial device, and my system creates a serial port for it when it is inserted. Good enough?

Comment: USB is a serial interface.  Exactly what chip is inline with your serial cable??  I'd start here:  https://www.google.com/search?q=USB+TO+RS232&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=USB+TO+RS232&tbm=shop  Just make sure your cable has drivers for the OS that you plan to use it with.

Comment: It's reported as a Prolific Tech. Inc. USB-Serial Controller. The serial connection works fine. Ok?

Comment: What is the part # of the chip?  If you have this one:  http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=107&pcid=41  It may work. Since it provides a UART that can be used with older serial interfaces.

Comment: It reads 'Prolific PL-2303'

Comment: Check here http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?pcid=41 for more info on that chip.  You're going to need the last 2 characters of that chip to positively identify it.

Comment: Here's a url for an Android solution:  http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=230&pcid=41